# ServiceNow reports to pull data related to changes

Tags: servicenow

How to create a report that give me the list of all the changes and it's associated "Affected CIs". So for e.g. I have a change ticket created in servicenow CHG00001 with following values for Configuration Item and Affected CIs:

- Change Number: CHG00001
- Configuration Item: Server1
- Affected CI:

  - 1. Apache
  - 2. JBoss

So when I create a report I need these information including all the affected CIs, but I don't see a way to pull that information.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `CIs Affected [task_ci]` table. This is the table that contains the links between the *Change Requests* and the *Configuration Item*.

The `Task` field in this table contains the reference to the *Change Request*.

In your report, try something like this

- Data: Table => CIs Affected [task_ci]
- Type: List
- Group by: Task

Selected columns

- Task
- Configuration Item

Filter

- Task.Task type **is** Change Request

You can expand the Task reference in your selected columns to get more details on your Change Request if needed, or filter them deeper.

If you've filtered the *Task type* as *Change Request*, you can select the extended table *Change Request* and filter it that way

Filter

- Task.Task type **is** Change Request
- Task.Change Request.Planned start date **at or after** Last month

Comment: Kirk: You the best :) this is exactly what was looking for. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Database Views** to create a single table created from multiple tables. Then you can use that table to show the report from.

There is a great video about this [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-performance-analytics-and-reporting/page/use/reporting/concept/c_HowToAccessRelatedTables.html). There is also a possibility to have [multiple data sets on the same report](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-performance-analytics-and-reporting/page/use/advanced_reporting/concept/c_MultipleDataSets.html).